# Is it expected behavior that I need to use an HTML entity in order to get less-than sign into my question?

Tags: support, design

I'm using SO on IE 9 and I never noticed this until recently (but can't remember if it ever worked).

In both the title and the body of a Question, in order to get angle brackets (and I assume ampersand) to appear it requires the use of HTML entities.

Is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: Ampersand works just fine as plaintext (&)

Comment: Definitely by design. I believe this is done to make HTML sanitizing easier -- `List <B> blah blah blah` is (relatively) hard to tell apart from `List <B>some bolded text</B>` for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is expected that you will put code into either the in-line code context (between backticks) or the block code context (indented by 4 spaces).

That is I can reference `List<T>` just fine, and I can have a longer code sample with angle brackets as well:

```
double fValue; ///< The weight associated with contributing
               ///  points. Only set after Eval(bool)
std::list<const point*> fList; ///< A list of test points in data
                               ///  space (x,y) that *might*
                               ///  contribute in this region
```

Comment: good enough for me